# PHP Regular Expression - Get number from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string sequence that goes like this: `<x:object*10/>`.
I want to replace that tag with something else that depends on what number it is.
I match the tag above with `/<x:object\*[0-9]+\/>/` and using preg_replace i can replace it all with the content I want. I just need that number now.

How can I get the number please?

Comment: what kind of markup is `<x:object*10/>` supposed to be?

Comment: It's a custom thingy from the CMS that tells the output parser to replace that with an object (Photo Gallery, VideoPlayer, AudioPlayer etc), having an ID of 10.

Comment: This is invalid XML though. Element names may not contain * characters. If you'd use well formed XML you wouldn't have to use Regex but could use a proper XML parser, like DOM.

Comment: That's true, I could just replace the star with `:`, but that never gets output. The parser changes that to a series of DIV elements and image tags etc.

Comment: That would be equally invalid XML. Strange parser you have there.

Comment: It's a custom built function that deals with that. It's more of a hack because clients change their minds right after all that was discussed is done...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By capturing it:

`/<x:object\*(?P<my_number>[0-9]+)\/>/`

It will be captured with name "my_number"...

Full code would be sth like this:

```
<?php
preg_match_all(`/<x:object\*(?P<my_number>[0-9]+)\/>/`, $where_to_search, $matches);
var_dump($matches); // Dump the matches to see in detail.
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :)

```
/<x:object\*([0-9]+)\/>/
```

Answer (score 0):

better use

```
/<x:object\*([0-9]+)\/>/
```

Comment: Hi, why add the extra forward slash?

Comment: bcoz `*` have diffrenet meaning in regex  and u have `*` in ur given string ,`\` is escape character

Comment: I know it has meaning in RegEx, that's why I'm escaping with with `\*`.

Comment: but u want to replace only numbers

Comment: Yup, `[0-9]+` is 1 or more times.

Comment: This is not a valid regular expression in PHP. `/<x:object/` will be treated as the expression, and then PHP fill throw an error because `*` is not a valid modifier. And what purpose has `^` here?

Comment: Now it's the same RegExp from the question. :)

Comment: @Francisc actually i m confused a bit...see now  at first i write that..then made a mistake while editing

Comment: @Francisc: Not sure if @dEcho changed something in between, but it is not the same expression. He used a capture group `()`.

Comment: Yeah, the brackets wheren't there nor were they in my initial RegExp.