# Separate string from numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, something like `max_length[5]`.  To validate, I need to be able to verify it has the structure of string (defined options of max_length, min_length, exact_length), [, numbers (any amount: 5, 121, 5322, etc), ].  Something like:

```
$string = 'max_length[5]';
$split = splitThis($string);  //replace splitThis() with a real function
//split looks like: array('max_length[]', 5) or something like that
```

If `$split` was able to come out as commented, then I could easily validate that `max_length[]` is a valid string, and `5` is a valid number. How would I do this?  Is it possible?  I have been searching for a similar scenario for hours now, and have not been able to get any other solutions to work for my problem.

Questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218407/php-regular-expression-get-number-from-string) are similar, but I haven't been able to get it working in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no specially difficult to do that. The only tricky thing is to design the pattern to extract interesting data easier:

```
function splitThis($str) {
    return preg_match('~\A(?:max|min|exact)_length(?=\[(\d+)]\z)~', $str, $m) ? $m : false;
}

print_r(splitThis("max_length[5]"));
```

pattern details:

```
~                          # pattern delimiter
\A                         # start of the string
(?:max|min|exact)_length
(?=                        # lookahead assertion: followed by:
    \[(\d+)]               # digits (captured in group 1) between square brackets 
    \z                     # end of the string
)
~
```

The lookahead is only a test, and all the subpattern inside is not a part of the whole match. So `preg_match` returns only "max_length" as whole match and the capture group 1, so "5".

usage:

```
if ( false !== ($result = splitThis($str)) ) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  You are much better at regular expressions that I could ever dream of being.  It may not give the brackets in the result, but with how it works, that is just fine.  If the brackets are not placed correctly, no result is given, so same end result just with a different approach.  It is still easy to verify if the submission is valid or not. The end result of `array('max_length', 5)` works perfectly for my needs.  Thank you so much!!  The explanation of the regex is also quite helpful.